# Create virtual/temporary layer from a GeoDataFrame in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, geopandas, gpx

I'm trying to make a plugin that lets me combine the Tracks from multiple GPX files into one virtual/temporary layer in QGIS.

Currently I have code that saves them as a GeoJSON layer but with a large number of files QGIS starts to hang.

Note: I am aware of the Batch GPS Importer plugin but unfortunately that plugin doesn't seem to maintain the `type` element associated with each track.

Here is my current code:

```
merged_tracks = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(
    columns=["name", "type", "geometry"], geometry="geometry"
)

for filename in self.filenames:
    tracks = geopandas.read_file(filename, layer="tracks")
    merged_tracks = pandas.concat(
        [merged_tracks, tracks[["name", "type", "geometry"]]]
    )

merged_layer = QgsVectorLayer(merged_tracks.to_json(), "merged-tracks", "ogr")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(merged_layer)
```

Comment: @BERA I have a couple of non-plugin versions (script, web app at https://tools.lostmapper.com/merge-gpx-tracks) where I merge the tracks into one layer and save as a GeoPackage file. I suppose I could go that route and just load the file as a layer, but wanted to give the user an option as to when and what they want to save it as - hence wanting to use a virtual layer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this could work.

First [create the memory layer](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#from-an-instance-of-qgsvectorlayer):

```py
layer = QgsVectorLayer("LineString", "merged-tracks", "memory")
provider = layer.dataProvider()

fields = QgsFields()
fields.append(QgsField("name", QVariant.String))
fields.append(QgsField("type",  QVariant.String))
provider.addAttributes(fields)

layer.updateFields()
```

Then, one possible approach is for each one of your dataframes iterate over the rows and add then as features the layer.

```py
mylist = []
for row in df.iterfeatures(na='null', show_bbox=False, drop_id=True):
    feature = QgsFeature()
    feature.setGeometry(...)
    feature.setAttributes(row["properties"]["name"], row["properties"]["type"])
    mylist.append(feature)

provider.addFeatures(mylist)
vl.updateExtents()
```

The problem is that obtaining a QgsGeometry from a GeoJSON feature [is not as easy as it should be](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/177264/pyqgis-add-geojson-as-editable-layer).

So it can be better just obtain the full representation of the dataframe as a GeoJSON string (as you are doing) and parse it with QGIS utility.

```py
features = QgsJsonUtils.stringToFeatureList(df.tojson(), fields)
provider.addFeatures(features)
vl.updateExtents()
```

Comment: Thank you. I will give this a try. Honestly I don’t want GeoJSON to be involved at all. It was just a temporary means to an end.

Comment: Do  you need the GeoDataFrame? I keep the GeoDataFrame in my answer because I think you need it, but it is possible to read a .gpx directly as a QgsVectorLayer.

Comment: I might not need the GeoDataFrame. I was just re-using code from a local script and simple web service I created. I should probably dig into what's possible with the Qgs API.

Comment: After doing some more digging I managed to turn your suggstion into a solution that doesn't use GeoPandas and just sticks to Qgs classes. Do you mind if I update your answer with the resulting code?

I guess that does change the nature of the question to omit GeoPandas, though...

Comment: It turns out what I came up with doesn't completely work for me. For some reason the Type attribute gets lost when not using GeoPandas. And I'm learning that QGIS is a bit inconsistent about how it loads GPX files.